# What are some method(s) default internationalization ".properties" with FXML?

Tags: java, internationalization, javafx, default, fxml

I would like to establish a default internationalization string properties resource for a FXML scene file.  The reference tutorial:

- [Internationalizing Your FXML Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/i18n-support.htm) see:

  - Preview menu item /

    - Internationalization command /

      - **Set Resource** ...

Describes how to set an international string and key pair.  I would like to have a default file to be used during SceneBuilder sessions and (*just in case*) there is ever a problem in the field with deployment or the media.

I realise we can't *ask* for changes to the FXML syntax and it isn't that much trouble to use the **set resource** (*above*) every time you open Scene Designer, just for the convenience or designing in a what-you-see-is-what-you-get (*wysiwyg*) for labels, messages, prompts, etc.

That said, I'd still like to see a mechanism to link to keep a '***sticky***' default internationalisation bundle in Scene Designer and at runtime.

What methods can you recommend to load or simulate a default bundle prior to FXML load/processing?

For example; I'd prefer it on my current exercise if the default bundle were loaded per scene.  However there will be other cases where a controller or group load for a default bundle is more suitable.    Also, is there a JavaFX pre-load hook to pre-process a scene (or FXML file) when loading?  *Thanks in advance*.

**see also**:

- [JavaFX 2 and Internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization)
- [Best practice for setting default values for model properties in Domain Driven Design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616611/best-practice-for-setting-default-values-for-model-properties-in-domain-driven-d)

Comment: I'm not sure about a sticky properties reference, but you can do some gruntwork before your scene is shown by using a `Preloader`. I'm afraid i don't know enough about the FXML loading process to inform you of a hook into preloading. However, your controller for your FXML can implement `Initializable`, which defines `initalize(URL, ResourceBundle)` and that will be called during the loading process once the FXML has been processed but has not been returned for use (so before the FXML is available for rendering).